# javascript not getting value of input box

Tags: javascript, textbox, getelementbyid

I seem to be having trouble with passing the value of an input box to anything else in my javascript.
It's not producing any errors - and I remember reading somewhere that you can have issues if the document hasn't finished loading - but I'm pretty sure it has!

The code in question is as follows in the javascript:

```
var address = getElementById(addyInput).value;
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = address;
```

And in the HTML

```
<form>
<input name="addyInput" placeholder="Don't forget postcode!">
</form>

<button id="start" onclick="initialize()">Start!</button>

<p>Address Test
<div id="add"></div>
</p>
```

I know that the button itself is working as it fires the rest of my code fine without the offending code - however the moment I uncomment that little block at the top, it just does nothing.  (no errors etc)

Any help on that one would be hot!  Thanks :)

Update:

I now have it working! Thanks muchly for all the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form needs to look like this (add an id attribute):

```
<form>
<input id="addyInput" name="addyInput" placeholder="Don't forget postcode!">
</form>
```

And the first line of Javascript needs to look like this (since `getElementById` is expecting an ID rather than a name).

```
var address = getElementById('addyInput').value;
```

Additionally, [`getElementById`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) expects the id argument to be a string (hence the quotes).  If you pass it `addyInput` without quotes, it'll try to interpret `addyInput` as a variable which has a value of undefined and you won't get back the DOM element you want.

---

Or, if you were using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you could leave the form markup as-is and change the Javascript to this:

```
var address = $('input[name=addyInput]').val();
```

Comment: thanks :) i originally had specified an id before, but as an experiment tried adding a name too - must have deleted the wrong one O_O can't believe i missed that!  still not working though :(

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to specify and `id` on the input. You only have a `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the id "addyInput" to your form input rather than just the name.

Answer (score 0):

getElementById expects a string.

`var address = getElementById('addyInput').value;`

If you put this directly into a script section in the head, then you will have a problem because the page is not loaded completely but the code is executed already.

And of course you should define an id for the input element as the others already said.

Comment: Ok I've done that but I'm still not getting anything - so how can I get around the issue of the page not being completely loaded?  Would I have to place the code somewhere in the actual page (like maybe the onclick for a button or something?)  thanks!

Comment: Sorry scratch that reply - I have it working but with a glitch now - I have it set up so it is passing the value of the textbox as an argument when the button is clicked - I have an alert set up for testing and also it is filling the DIV like at the top - the problem is it is giving me the correct value in the alert, but the DIV is just displaying [Object object]

Answer (score -1):

what you are getting is an array, you need to fetch your array into some readable data. Try something like:

- `$value = array_shift( $yourarray );`

or if it's a multi value array you can just loop it to fetch out the values.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with php.